# Partial string match python like Vlookup

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup, partial

I have the following dataframes:

```py
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Invoice': ['3 HongKong', 'A Africa', 'A GhanaLimited', 'AfricaGroup'],
                        'Currency': ['EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'USD']})

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Ref': ['3 Hong', 'A Africa', 'A Ghana', 'Africa Group'],
                        'Type': ['01', '03', '04', '02'],
                        'Amount': ['Live', 'No', 'Live', 'No'],
                        'Comment': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla']})

    print(df1)
    print(df2)

              Invoice Currency
    0      3 HongKong      EUR
    1        A Africa      EUR
    2  A GhanaLimited      EUR
    3     AfricaGroup      USD
                Ref Type Amount Comment
    0        3 Hong   01   Live     bla
    1      A Africa   03     No     bla
    2       A Ghana   04   Live     bla
    3  Africa Group   02     No     bla
```

I would like to create a new dataframe (df3) where I combine the two based on the invoice . The problem is that the invoice numbers are not always a "full match", but sometimes a "partial match" in df2['Ref']. So the joining on 'Invoice' does not give the desired output because it doesn't copy the data for invoices.

I tried the following code :

```py
    df4 = df1.copy()

    def get_amount(x):
       return df2.loc[df2['Ref'].str.contains(x), 'Amount'].iloc[0]

    df4['Amount'] = df4['Invoice'].apply(get_amount)
```

But this gives me error:

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Can this problem be solved ?